# Defining 2D irregular array with malloc

Tags: arrays, malloc, heap-memory

I have this practice question:

Define a 2D irregular array with malloc of ints where the out dim = 4 and the inner = 10,11,12,13. (hint: use a for loop)

So, I realized that I could write a 2D irregular array with malloc of ints like this:

int (*array)[20] = malloc((sizeof *array) * 10);

That would be for a 10x20 array I believe with amlloc.

I'm just not sure how I would use a for loop to change the inner dimension from 10 to 11 to 12 to 13. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

```
int j;

for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++ )
{
    for ( j = 10; j < 14; j++ )
    {
        int (*array)[4] = malloc((sizeof *array) * j)
    }
}
```

By the way, is that close to correct?

Comment: Add 1 to the ending value of the inner `for` loop each time you make one execution of the outer `for` loop.

Comment: Is what I added close to correct?

Comment: Yes, you just need something like `j < 10 + k` in the second `for`.  See how that works?

Comment: For some reason, I get an error under malloc. It says a value of type void cannot be used to initialize an entity of type int "int(*)[4]"

Comment: Did it work before you made the change I suggested?

Comment: No not really. It had the same error both times.

Comment: Ok, well someone who has better C knowledge than I will have to help you fix that malloc.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?
If so, please edit http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Common_practices#Dynamic_multidimensional_arrays to make it easier for the next student to understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int rows = 20;

int main(void) {
    int **some_data;
    // first, allocate a (column) Iliffe vector.
    some_data = malloc( (sizeof(*some_data)) * rows);
    int i=0;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        // next, allocate each row.
        // For no good reason, make each row a different size.
        int columns = i+10;
        some_data[i] = malloc( (sizeof(**some_data)) * columns);
    };
    some_data[3][13] = 9;
    printf( "%d\n", some_data[3][13]);
    return 0;
}
```

If you are viewing this through one of the locked-down systems that seem to be inexplicably popular nowadays, you may find it convenient to run the above code in some online C compilers such as http://ideone.com/ or http://codepad.org/ or http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php .